# Link between Standard Normal R.V. transofrmation to polar coordinates and orthogonal matrices

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this problem which has 2 parts:

1) Let $X, Y$  be independent standard normal r.v. define $R, \theta$ by $X=R\cos\theta$ $Y=R\sin\theta$ and find the joint distribution of $R,\theta$.

2) Consider $Z_1,...,Z_n$ iid standard normal r.v. and $A$ be an orthogonal matrix.
Find the joint distribution of $W1,...,W_n$ where $W=AZ$

Now I can do without too many problems both parts, in particular I get that the distri. of the $W_i$ is  still a multivariate standard normal.

Now I'm asked to explain the link of part 2 to part 1... I don't really know what is meant by that as trasformation to polar coordinates is not even linear... 
Any idea or hint would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Is your definition of _orthogonal matrix_ a matrix $A$ such that $AA^T$ is a _diagonal_ matrix or the _identity_ matrix (in which case $A$ is often referred to as an _orthonormal_ matrix)? If $AA^T$ is a diagonal matrix but not the identity matrix, then the $W_i$ would be zero-mean independent normal random variables but the variances would be the diagonal entries in $AA^T$ which would not all equal $1$.

Comment: we define it to be a matrix such that the inverse it's the same as the transpose! probably calling it orthonormal would be more precise though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, think of the meaning of an orthogonal matrix.

Is this matrix orthogonal?

\begin{eqnarray*}
  A & = & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    \cos \phi & - \sin \phi\\
    \sin \phi & \cos \phi
  \end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, $\theta$ is a uniform random variable on the circle (Independent of $R$ which gives the norm of $(X,Y)$. What happens if you rotate by $\phi$ a vector with uniform angle? Does the norm change? Does the distribution of the angle change?

---

Incidentally, the property studied here is that the normal distribution is **invariant** under orthogonal transformations. More generally, distributions having the property of being obtained from a uniformly distributed point on the $n$ sphere with a (independent) random length are called spherical and they share the property that they are invariant under orthogonal transformations. The standard normal is  a special case. (The spherical distributions are themselves a special case of the elliptical distributions...)

Comment: yes that one is a rotation... applying it to (X,Y)^(t) I would get the vector (R,0), I thought of this but it did not really make much sense to me...

Comment: @Moritzplatz I added more explanation and added a new letter for the angle of the rotation to clarify your previous confusion.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now, thanks! 
Essentially using polar coordinates was a way to make more intuitive the invariance under orthogonal transformations which is proved in the second part?

Comment: @Moritzplatz Yes. I believe that was the point of the exercise.